# How to get stack usage in gcc when link-time optimization is enabled?

Tags: gcc, cortex-m

I's using arm-none-eabi-gcc 9.2.1 to develop programs for Cortex-M0, I found that the option -fstack-usage does not work if -flto is used. Is it possible to do static stack usage analyze when link-time-optimization is enabled?

Comment: Going by [this bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=98922), it looks like you'll be able to do this by upgrading to a version of arm-none-eabi-gcc based on gcc 10 or later. Though the files won't have the names and locations you probably expect and you'll need to read that bug report to know where to find them.

Comment: (Posted as a comment instead of an answer, since I don't know whether you're in a situation where you have to use that particular version of the cross-compiler). Also, AFAICT it hasn't yet upgraded to gcc 11, just 10. 11's behaviour with regard to this bug is quite a bit improved compared to 10.